# CSS - Changing the behaviour of certain class only within a div's

Tags: css, extjs

I'm using ExtJS 4 for my frontend where I have a tree and all child nodes have offset from the root node which is accompliesh by two transperant `<img.../>` each with his own class. I want to remove the offset and all child nodes to be right under the root which is easily accomplished by just settind the `width` of one of the `<img../> classes` to something like:

```
.img_class_1 {
width : 0px;
}
```

which in fact Im using at the moment. The problem is that I'm not sure if I or someone else in the future won't need this class with it's original begaviour so my question is - does the CSS syntax allows to set e differenet behavioour for a class just within a certain `<div id..>`. Just to make it clear I want my `class = "img_class_1"` to have `width: 0px` only within the div with `id = "img_container"` and everywhere outside the div with this id I want my class to keep it's original behaviour. Is it possible within CSS and how can I do that?

Thanks

Leron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your selector more specific:

```
#img_container .img_class_1 {
  width : 0px;
}
```

`a b c` selects the `c` element which is inside of a `b` element which is inside of an `a` element (not necessarily a direct child, but a descendant).

Comment: Thanks, gonna try it after 20-30min when I'm at work an accept your answer. Cheers :)